# How can update my cumulative column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe named 'df' with 4 columns: date, game_name, total_registered,newly_registered

The total registered column is a cumulative column.

**Sample:**

```
+------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
|    date    | game_name | total_registered | newly_registered |
+------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| 2020-12-1  | abc       |               10 |                4 |
| 2020-12-2  | abc       |               14 |                3 |
| 2020-12-3  | abc       |                0 |                5 |
| 2020-12-1  | zzz       |               20 |                2 |
| 2020-12-2  | zzz       |               22 |               10 |
| 2020-12-3  | zzz       |                0 |                5 |
+------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
```

As you can see, my cumulative column broke on the 2nd for 'abc' and on the 3rd for 'zzz'

To be safe I would like to redo my cumulative column starting on the 2nd. How can modify the current row total_registered by taking the prior day's total_registered+newly_registered values of its respective game?

**Desired Output:**

```
+------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
|    date    | game_name | total_registered | newly_registered |
+------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| 2020-12-1  | abc       |               10 |                4 |
| 2020-12-2  | abc       |               14 |                3 |
| 2020-12-3  | abc       |               17 |                5 |
| 2020-12-1  | zzz       |               20 |                2 |
| 2020-12-2  | zzz       |               22 |               10 |
| 2020-12-3  | zzz       |               32 |                5 |
+------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: What's your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concept

1. pick out first **total_registered** for each group name it **newly_registered** and put against epoch date
2. `concat()` with actual data
3. recalculate **total_registered** using `cumsum()` and `shift()` including data from step 1

```
import io
import datetime as dt
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    date    | game_name | total_registered | newly_registered |
| 2020-12-1  | abc       |               10 |                4 |
| 2020-12-2  | abc       |               14 |                3 |
| 2020-12-3  | abc       |                0 |                5 |
| 2020-12-1  | zzz       |               20 |                2 |
| 2020-12-2  | zzz       |               22 |               10 |
| 2020-12-3  | zzz       |                0 |                5 |"""),sep="\s*\|\s*", skipinitialspace=True, engine="python").reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns="Unnamed: 4")

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df = (pd.concat([df,
# synthesize first total_registered into a new row as newly_registered
(df.groupby("game_name").first()
 .reset_index()
 .assign(date=pd.to_datetime(dt.date(1970,1,1)),
        newly_registered=lambda dfa: dfa["total_registered"])
)
])
 .sort_values(["game_name","date"])
 # total_registered is now simple cumsum with a shift in group
 .assign(total_registered=lambda dfa: dfa.groupby("game_name")["newly_registered"]
         .transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift())
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int))
 # remove synthesized rows
 .query("date.dt.year>1970")
)
```

### output

```
      date game_name  total_registered  newly_registered
2020-12-01       abc                10                 4
2020-12-02       abc                14                 3
2020-12-03       abc                17                 5
2020-12-01       zzz                20                 2
2020-12-02       zzz                22                10
2020-12-03       zzz                32                 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `date` is a sorted per `game_name` group (Otherwise have to be sorted per group).

As the cumulative is per `game_name` group, you have to group by and then in the group dataframe, get the cumulative using first `total_registered` value, and all the `newly_registered` values in the particular group to get the final `total_registered` column.

```
def func(x):
    result = x['newly_registered'].shift(1)  # as the last value would not be needed
    result.iloc[0] = x['total_registered'].iloc[0]  # adding the total_registered first value at top
    return result.cumsum().to_frame()

df['total_registered'] = (df.groupby('game_name')[['total_registered','newly_registered']]
                          .apply(func))
df

    date      game_name total_registered  newly_registered
0   2020-12-1    abc       10.0            4
1   2020-12-2    abc       14.0            3
2   2020-12-3    abc       17.0            5
3   2020-12-1    zzz       20.0            2
4   2020-12-2    zzz       22.0            10
5   2020-12-3    zzz       32.0            5
```